# Does /proc/cmdline contain spaces after "="?

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, linux-kernel, cmdline-args

I have written a script to read a parameter from cmdline.
Ex. TARGET=X86.
Here My question is, can somebody give space after/before "="?
because in my test application i am searching the entire string "TARGET=X86".   Is there any rule for writing cmdline?

Comment: "TARGET" is not a standard option. However it is defined is how it is defined.

Comment: No spaces: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html

Comment: @hek2mgl, Thanks